# True or False: $(n + \log(n))(n+8)$ is $O(n)$

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

Just wondering if I can get some feedback regarding this proof, and whether or not there is a way to do it without limits.

My Solution:

$(n + \log(n))(n+8)$ is not $O(n)$

Suppose by contradiction that $(n + \log(n))(n+8)$ is O(n). Then there exists c > 0 and $n_0 \geq 1$ such that:

$(n + log(n))(n+8) \le c \cdot n $

$n^2 + 8n + nlog(n) + 8log(n) \le c \cdot n$

$\frac{(n^2 + 8n + nlog(n) + 8log(n))}{n} \le c$

$n + 8 + log(n) + \frac{8log(n))}{n} \le c$

$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} (n + 8 + log(n) + \frac{8log(n))}{n} ) = \infty $

The left side approaches infinity and therefore will never be less than a constant. This leads to a contradiction.  $(n + \log(n))(n+8)$ is not $O(n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct indeed

$$ (n + \log n)(n+8)=n^2+8n+n\log n + 8 \log n=O(n^2)$$

Comment: Is it necessary to do the limit or can you just use the dominant x^2 term?

Comment: @JaredL The definition is nor the limit nor the dominat term but in that case the $2$ methods are equivalent.